# Should questions related to school, teaching and education be considered on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions related to school, teaching and education be considered on topic?

Some examples:

[education](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) - [Examples:](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education?tab=Newest)
[How to encourage my 5-year-old who seems to be unusually interested in astronomy?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/36087/)
[At what age should a child be able to differentiate basic homonyms in writing?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/35528/)
[Does teaching my daughter programming give them the same benefits as when I learned electronics as a child?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/32704/)

[teaching](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) - [Examples:](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching?tab=Newest)
[Is it okay to raise a child by teaching them numbers in base 16?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/37804/)
[How to explain addition vs. place values to a 4½-year-old?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/37477/)
[Teaching young children about American Indian history](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/30331/)

[school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school) - [Examples:](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school?tab=Newest)
[Does the Montessori method allow a child to choose the same lesson every day without guidance?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/33362/)
[Better to struggle taking Honors/AP courses or take easier courses?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/29350/)
[Has any research been done on benefits of Montessori schooling?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/27074/)

**SEE ALSO:**

No clear consensus against questions related to school, teaching and education emerged in the past:
[Where do we draw the line between teaching and parenting?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/295)
[Should questions about teaching and curriculum/academics be closed as off-topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193)

It is time to revisit this issue, since the recent discussions in comments indicate a lack of clarity on this issue in the community (links to comments omitted to avoid the meta effect).

Answer (score 2):

**Questions related to school, teaching and education should be considered on topic, provided they are relevant to parents.** That is, if the parent is affected because the child lives with the parent or someone who cares for children, as is typical for kids up to and including high school. This is because these issues typically affect both the children and the parents, both directly and indirectly. Specifically, the above example questions should continue being considered on topic.

Off-topic: questions that are much too specialized, clearly do not affect parents, and/or are a better fit on other sites—such as [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) for questions about higher education.